# Maven pom file inheritance of scope

Tags: java, maven

I have the following definition in a parent pom:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>net.sourceforge.htmlunit</groupId> 
  <artifactId>htmlunit</artifactId> 
  <version>2.11</version> 
  <scope>test</scope>      
</dependency>
```

And then this in my child pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.htmlunit</groupId>
    <artifactId>htmlunit</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I am finding that when my WAR file (the packaging type in my child pom) is built that transitive dependencies from htmlunit are included in the WEB-INF/lib directory (in particular commons-codec).

I would have thought that because the dependency has a scope of 'test' that it and any of its transitive dependencies should not be packaged. Is my assumption incorrect?

Answer (score 4):

Your assumption is incorrect. Since you have provided scope `test`, this jar will be present for both test and execution phase.

The scope should have been `provided` instead. The scope `provided` will make the jar available on the compilation and test classpath, and is not transitive.

Refer to http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html [dependency scope section](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope) for more details.